# How do you create an NSError object with underlying errors?

Tags: swift, nserror

For unit testing purposes, I need to be able to create an `NSError` object with the `underlyingErrors` property set to a certain error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always favor using the declared vars like `NSPOSIXErrorDomain` or `NSCocoaErrorDomain` instead of string literals. Note that there are already declared `CocoaError` and `POSIXError` structs that you can use to generate those errors:

```
func createFilesystemError() -> NSError {
    NSError(
        domain: CocoaError.errorDomain,
        code: CocoaError.fileNoSuchFile.rawValue,
        userInfo: [
            NSUnderlyingErrorKey: NSError(
                domain: POSIXError.errorDomain,
                code: Int(POSIXError.ENOENT.rawValue)
            )
        ]
    )
}
```

But the correct way to create these erros is to initialize and cast them to `NSError` if needed:

```
extension CocoaError {
    static let fileNotFound: CocoaError = .init(
        .fileNoSuchFile,
        userInfo: [
            NSUnderlyingErrorKey: POSIXError(.ENOENT)
        ]
    )
}
```

---

```
extension NSError {
    static let fileNotFound = CocoaError.fileNotFound as NSError
}
```

---

```
createFilesystemError() == .fileNotFound   // true
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested your answer and it works! It definitely seems like the more proper way to do it compared to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. You have to use the `userInfo` field when initializing your NSError. Here's an example that creates an error that is usually thrown by FileManager when you try to delete a file that does not exist:

```
func createFilesystemError() -> NSError {
  let underlyingNSError = NSError(domain: "NSPOSIXErrorDomain", code: 2)
  let userInfo = [NSUnderlyingErrorKey: underlyingNSError]
  return NSError(domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain", code: 4, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```